# trying to implement jaccard smilarity in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was trying to build a Jaccard Similarity using the `gds.nodesimilarity` in neo4j but its giving me an error in nested for loop.

Comment: what is the error you are getting? can you give us sample data.

Comment: You cannot use FOREACH for anything else that write subqueries. Try using UNWIND instead

Answer (score 1):

Aside from syntax error on foreach within another foreach, the jaccard similarity parameters are list of categorical measures and NOT numerical values in the variable kou.

```
for example; jaccard between [1, 2, 3, 4, 6] and [1, 3, 6] is 0.60
```

BUT you are doing jaccard between 1 and 1, 1 and 3 and 1 and 6 and so on.

Below is a sample working query that is using the Movie Recommendation dataset in Neo4j. It will calculate the jaccard similarity of the movie 'Toy Story' (my favorite) to other movies based on Genre.

```
MATCH (a:Movie{title: 'Toy Story'}), (b:Movie) where a <> b 
WITH a, b limit 10
CALL { 
     WITH a, b  
     MATCH (a)-[:IN_GENRE]-> (g1:Genre) 
     RETURN  a.title as titleA,  b.title as titleB, collect(id(g1)) as countA, [] as countB
  UNION ALL
     WITH a, b
     MATCH (b)-[:IN_GENRE]-> (g2:Genre)  
     RETURN  a.title as titleA,  b.title as titleB, [] as countA, collect(id(g2)) as countB  
} 
WITH titleA, titleB, apoc.coll.flatten(collect(countA)) as countA, apoc.coll.flatten(collect(countB)) as countB  
RETURN titleA, titleB, gds.similarity.jaccard(countA, countB) as jaccard order by jaccard desc
```

Result:

```
╒═══════════╤═════════════════════════════╤═══════════════════╕
│"titleA"   │"titleB"                     │"jaccard"          │
╞═══════════╪═════════════════════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│"Toy Story"│"Jumanji"                    │0.6                │
├───────────┼─────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│"Toy Story"│"Father of the Bride Part II"│0.2                │
├───────────┼─────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│"Toy Story"│"Grumpier Old Men"           │0.16666666666666666│
├───────────┼─────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│"Toy Story"│"Waiting to Exhale"          │0.14285714285714285│
├───────────┼─────────────────────────────┼───────────────────┤
│"Toy Story"│"Heat"                       │0.0                │
└───────────┴─────────────────────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use gds.similarity function inside foreach. Foreach is used to update data within that collection. Please check the below link https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/foreach/